# MYSQL query same field for two different ids

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

my MYSQL kung fu is weak and am in need of some guidance, here are my 2 tables:

```
TABLE SHIPS

id |  ship_name
1     recon ship
2     light fighter
3     heavy fighter
4     light cruiser

TABLE FLEET

user_id | ship_id | amt
173          1       3
173          2       4
173          3       1
173          4       0
169          1       5
169          2       2
169          3       0
169          4       0
```

For my output I am trying to get data like this:

```
ship_name      | amt1 | amt2
recon ship        3       5
light fighter     4       2
heavy fighter     1       0
```

where amt1 is user 173 amounts and amt2 is user 169 amounts.  I hope I have made myself clear on this, and THANKS!

EDIT:  I added one more ship and the case where both users have amt=0 for said ship, how can I omit from the result such a case, I have tried in a WHERE clause but it keeps telling me I have an error

Comment: you are actually trying to use mysql to make a pivot table.. can I assume you only want this two users or you are thinking that columns amt1, amt2 are generated dynamically, so that if you got a new user later on, you want to see column amt3 as well, without changing sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for your basic needs according to your question.

```
SELECT  a.ship_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.user_ID = 173 THEN amt END) amt1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.user_ID = 169 THEN amt END) amt2
FROM    Ships a
        INNER JOIN Fleet b
            ON  a.id = b.ship_ID AND
                b.user_ID IN (173, 169)
GROUP   BY a.ship_name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83527/3)

If you want to return all `user_ID` without specifying any values on the statement, then a *dynamic SQL* is much preferred.

**UPDATE 1**

add `HAVING` clause,

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    ...
GROUP   BY ....
HAVING  MAX(CASE WHEN b.user_ID = 173 THEN amt END) <> 0 AND
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.user_ID = 169 THEN amt END) <> 0
```

Comment: Bingo, thanks.  Don't need dynamic just need to compare two users

Comment: If you could edit your response for my edited question, would be grateful... again ;)

Comment: Great stuff!  just change the AND to an OR in the HAVING clause and that is exactly what I am looking for